# How do I make an argument with unknown n number of values stored in an array when parsed using docopt

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface, docopt

I want a command line argument to be in an array format.

i.e

```bash
myprogram.py -a 1,2,4,5
```

and when the argument is parsed using `docopt`, I want to see:

```
{'a' = [1,2,4,5]}  # the length of this array could be as long as user may like.
```

I don't know if this is possible or not. If not what is the best adjustment I could make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get `docopt` to do this, as the comma separated list is just considered a optional argument. But you could easily do it yourself afterwards:

```
"""
Example of program with many options using docopt.

Usage:
  myprogram.py -a NUMBERS

Options:
  -h --help            show this help message and exit
  -a NUMBERS           Comma separated list of numbers
"""

from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__, version='1.0.0rc2')
    args['-a'] = [int(x) for x in args['-a'].split(',')]
    print(args)
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer would be to use an ellipsis `...`

From the docopt documentation

> ... (ellipsis) one or more elements. To specify that arbitrary number of repeating elements could be accepted, use ellipsis (...), e.g. `my_program.py FILE ...` means one or more FILE-s are accepted. If you want to accept zero or more elements, use brackets, e.g.: `my_program.py [FILE ...]`. Ellipsis works as a unary operator on the expression to the left.

Using the [online parser](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Naval+Fate.%0D%0A%0D%0AUsage%3A%0D%0A++naval_fate.py+ship+new+%3Cname%3E...%0D%0A++naval_fate.py+-h+%7C+--help%0D%0A++naval_fate.py+--version%0D%0A%0D%0AOptions%3A%0D%0A++-h+--help+++++Show+this+screen.%0D%0A++--version+++++Show+version.%0D%0A%0D%0A&argv=ship+new+1+2+3+4) you can see the output.

Given a docopt of

```
Naval Fate.

Usage:
  naval_fate.py ship new <name>...
  naval_fate.py -h | --help
  naval_fate.py --version

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.
```

An input of `ship new 1 2 3 4` will give you the following parsed information

```json
{
  "--help": false, 
  "--version": false, 
  "<name>": [
    "1", 
    "2", 
    "3", 
    "4"
  ], 
  "new": true, 
  "ship": true
}
```

Comment: Nice to know that this option exists too. However, I've not been able to get this to work with `--name` so that the command would be something like `naval_fate.py ship new --name=1 2 3 4` instead.